# Cannot switch 5v relay with adapter power supply

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3

I have designed a circuit to trigger a relay with GPIO port. I have used pin 4 for 5v as Vcc to my circuit, pin 6 for ground and pin 8 (BCM 14) as GPIO (output in this case). Further the pin 8 is connected to relay with PNP transistor 2n3906 and a diode with some resistor as in the image [image]

There is no problem when I connect raspberry pi with laptop usb port as power. But when I connect the system (raspberry pi along with my designed ckt) to adapter (came along with raspberry pi) the relay do not trigger. All linux thing is working. I can see the programming logic all working fine with putty. So, I want to know if there is anyone out there facing such problem, if yes or if I am doing anything wrong please suggest the solution. The only issue I see is with adapter power ( which i think shouldn't be).

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.  The only difference is the quality of the power supply.

Comment: This is a bad idea!. You are connecting 12V to the GPIO (via a diode - B-E). You almost certainly are not saturating the transistor, even if you haven't damaged the GPIO. Try a more conventional circuit with a NPN transistor.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly uploaded wrong image. Now i have edited the post. I am using 5v only, and the relay is also a 5vdc type.

Comment: 5V is not as bad as 12V, but my earlier comments still apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NPN transistor like 2N2222. Connect it like in this schematic. It should work. If it doesn't, make sure the adapter provides enough current.

[image: Circuit]